# using ddply to summarize when not all combinations exist

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to count the number of observations that occurred in each month for a combination of a site and variable. For example, my data are in the format

```
station variable date       month
A         v1      1/1/2011    1
A         v1      1/1/2012    1
```

etc.

So, I would like the output of `ddply` to be:

```
station  variable   Jan
A        v1          2
```

Here is my first stab at the ddply code:

```
months <- ddply(seasons, c("station", "variable"), summarize,
              Jan = length(month=1),
              Feb = length(month=2),
              Mar = length(month=3),
              Apr = length(month=4),
              May = length(month=5),
              Jun = length(month=6),
              Jul = length(month=7),
              Aug = length(month=8),
              Sep = length(month=9),
              Oct = length(month=10),
              Nov = length(month=11),
              Dec = length(month=12))
```

However, for some station/variable combinations, a month was never sampled. So, if for example, Station B was never sampled in January, I get an error:

```
Error in length(month = 1) : 
  supplied argument name 'month' does not match 'x'
```

I have tried putting an `ifelse()` statement to set the value to zero if month=x does not exist, but nothing I tried work. I have also tried prefilling the dataframe "months" with zeros, but that also didn't work.

Suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for making the formatting better, Henrik!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
## make some data like yours
set.seed(1)
dat <- seq(as.POSIXct(42, origin = "1990-01-01"), Sys.time(), length.out = 100)
seasons <- data.frame(
  station = sample(LETTERS[1:10], length(dat), TRUE),
  variable = paste0("v", sample(1:5, length(dat), TRUE)),
  date = dat,
  month = as.integer(format(dat, "%m"))
  )

head(seasons)
##   station variable                date month
## 1       C       v4 1989-12-31 19:00:42    12
## 2       D       v2 1990-03-30 18:45:47     3
## 3       F       v2 1990-06-27 19:30:52     6
## 4       J       v5 1990-09-24 19:15:57     9
## 5       C       v4 1990-12-22 18:01:02    12
## 6       I       v2 1991-03-21 17:46:07     3

library(plyr)

out <- ddply(seasons, .(station, variable), function(x)
             table(factor(x$month, levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb)))

head(out)
##   station variable Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
## 1       A       v1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
## 2       A       v2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
## 3       A       v3   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
## 4       A       v4   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
## 5       B       v1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
## 6       B       v3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Thanks to @Henrik for the `month.abb` trick

Comment: Instead of `substr(month.name, 1, 3)` you may use `month.abb`.